# Is it possible to pass object instances from parent to iFrame cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, communication

Is there a way for the parent to pass-in a reference of an object declared in a function in the parent window to be accessible to a child iFrame?

Using postMessage doesn't do the trick, especially as IE9 doesn't support objects and data needs to be serialized before sending.

Could this be achieved by loading a script in the parent document which is hosted on the same domain (protocol, port etc) as the iFrame document? If so, how would that work?

Thanks.